# Vercel deployment build failed with command npm install exited with 1

Tags: reactjs, vercel

When I am deploying react project on Vercel, build failed with this kind of message.
Command "npm install" exited with 1.
Here is the error log.

```
npm ERR!   g++ '-DNODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=libsass' '-DUSING_UV_SHARED=1' '-DUSING_V8_SHARED=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1' '-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS' '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1' '-D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS' '-DOPENSSL_NO_PINSHARED' '-DOPENSSL_THREADS' '-DLIBSASS_VERSION="3.5.5"' -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.15.0/include/node -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.15.0/src -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.15.0/deps/openssl/config -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.15.0/deps/openssl/openssl/include -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.15.0/deps/uv/include -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.15.0/deps/zlib -I/vercel/.node-gyp/16.15.0/deps/v8/include -I../src/libsass/include  -fPIC -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -m64 -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++14 -std=c++0x -fexceptions -frtti -MMD -MF ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o.d.raw   -c -o Release/obj.target/libsass/src/libsass/src/ast.o ../src/libsass/src/ast.cpp
```

Here is screen shot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOmvp.png)

How can I solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met that kind of case on this year.
I think that is because of node version.
The vercel's default node version is the latest one. I think 16.x.
But your project may should work with lower node version.
Please have a check the node version.
I attached screen shot of how you can check the node version on vercel.
[image]

Comment: GREAT! GENIOUS!

Comment: Your answer helped me in solving the problem. Thank you very much.!!!

Comment: mine those not have this option

Answer (score 0):

just check for the version of eslint and update to the latest using

```
npm show eslint version
node i eslint@latest
```

and update the vite or react version you are using

```
node i vite@latest
```

pro tip: exclude the unnecessary dependencies you are using in package.json